# Tableau how to bar plot grand totals of sub-categories

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

Using Analysis -> Totals -> Show Column Grand Totals only display grand total by sub-category in cross-tab format as is shown below.

[image]

But I wish to put the grand totals into a bar plot the same as the respective regions as is shown below.

[image]

Could somebody teach me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a hierarchy and use the hierarchy to achieve your objective.

1. Create the hierarchy
2. Put the hierarchy field in your pane
3. Using Analysis -> Totals -> SubTotals

You will get your desired result